# How to create random memory allocation failure?

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory, ulimit, pageheap

I recently discovered [PageHeap](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286470/en-us), a Windows debugging tool. Its option **/fault** permits injecting memory allocation failure every once in a while. Like, I want 1 allocation to fail every 100, or 1000, you decide. Do we have something similar on linux?

I can think of ulimit, but this is not quite the same thing, it will make every subsequent allocations fails once the memory is reached, not just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do similar things using `LD_PRELOAD`; you’ll need to compile something like the following:

```
#include <dlcfn.h>

void *malloc(size_t size) {
  static unsigned count = 0;
  static void *(*real_malloc)(size_t) = NULL;

  if (!real_malloc)
    real_malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");

  if (++count == 100) {
    count = 0;
    return NULL;
  }

  return real_malloc (size);
}
```

as a shared object, e.g. with

```
gcc -shared -ldl -fPIC my_malloc.c -o libmy_malloc.so
```

Once you’ve done so, you can run your program like so:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libmy_malloc.so ./my_program
```

and it will call the replacement `malloc()` routine.

I imagine there are pre-built versions of the above with more debugging features than that, but you get the idea.

Oh, by the way, *the above code is not tested (written in Stack Overflow)*.  It is also **not thread safe**, and **you need to be thread safe** if replacing malloc(), so you’ll want to use `pthread_once()`, and the `pthread_mutex` APIs to fix that.

Comment: This is interesting. Can I assume that `operator new` will call this malloc too?

Comment: @qdii: No, but you can replace that too. It's even standard in C++ so you don't need a `LD_PRELOAD` hack.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to write your own. Take a look at: [Malloc Hooks](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html).